# CSS - center text on page and left justify it

Tags: html, css

Working on designing a website and am having issues getting my text to center on the page while also keeping it left justified. The section I'm trying to apply this effect to is h3. I'm missing something obvious but I'm at a loss atm. Thanks!

Below is my code:

***HTML***

```
<section id="marketing" class="section fp-section" data-anchor="thirdPage">
    <img id="marketingLogo" src="images/marketing.png">
    <h2 align="center"> Text goes here</h2>
    <h3 align="center"> Text goes here</h3>
```

***CSS***

```
.fp-section h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Use div... and attribute align. headers doesnt have align atribute.

Comment: what's your ultimate goal? it's not really clear what you want to achieve since the text can be either *left* **or** *center* aligned, but not both

Comment: The goal is to keep the text in the middle of the screen and left align it.  Maybe a new centered div box with the text left aligned inside of it?

Comment: Something like https://jsfiddle.net/amL9b8f9/3/

Comment: That's perfect uom-pregorio. Got to love overthinking something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `align: center` from the html, first of all it's best to keep your html and css separate and second because you don't need that in there.

Second, you need to set the css to this:

```
.fp-section h3{
    width: 10em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

This works because you've given it a definitive width, therefore, when it the line is too long or something like that it will wrap and still be in the center, and you already had the `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` thing figured out so that's done and done.

Also, sidenote: I changed your font-size from pixels to ems just because I think that ems work better across different systems.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to do something similar to what i want to do. Display a block of text in the center of the screen, but the block of text itself is justified

Comment: Is this an answer?

Answer (score -1):

You may just need to add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to your heading.

Edit: Although saying that, what you're asking seems to be conflicting. If you want it centred but left aligned, how would you see that being displayed?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have inline style (align="center") on your  elements that takes precedence over your stylesheet.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity